# Azure Deployment Center Setup Broken

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I have previously set up Azure Deployment with GitHub, but yesterday the builds stopped syncing and the interface seemed to hang.  I have removed the existing deployment configuration, to started again.

The setup journey (which I believe seems to have changed in the last week or so) hangs - it is not possible to complete the setup journey.  I get though the first 2 steps, SOURCE CONTROL --> BUILD PROVIDER, but then the third step CONFIGURATION hangs with a project 'validating' spinner.

[image: Please click for screenshot of the issue]

I encounter the same issue across multiple Azure app services.  Anyone else experienced this or have any thought or suggestions?

Comment: Its validating is loading the project, please ensure your smooth Internet speed. I test in my site and have no problem.